# One widget area for footer instead of 3? [wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, grid, footer

I have a WooCommerce shop setup with the theme Retailer. The theme is currently setup to have 3 footer widget placeholders by using grids to allow 3 widgets to be placed. What I essentially want is to be just one widget with 1 grid that takes the width of the whole page/main container.

I have tried this and had success:

**Footer Widget CSS**

```
.container_12 .grid_4 { //Expands widget to width of container
    width: 100%;
}
```

However when I did this, my shop sidebar menu to the left disappears. When I remove that CSS, footer goes back to the way is now and sidebar appears.

Refer to this page to see what I mean: http://museiam.ca/product-category/men/

Currently I took out the CSS code for the widget which is why the shop menu is displaying. But notice how the footer menu is messed up. Essentially, I want it to be centered all in one line in the center like so:

http://tinypic.com/r/jrv9mq/8

Here is the CSS for the grid that hold the sidebar:

**Shop Sidebar CSS**

```
.container_12 .pull_9 {
left: -820px !important;
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these 3 lines of CSS inside your stylesheet will fix everything and make the footer content appear centered in the middle without affecting the sidebar:

```
.gbtr_dark_footer_wrapper .container_12 .grid_3 {
     width: 100%;
}
```

What the above code does is that it specifically targets the `.grid_3` inside the footer and increases its width from `220px` to `100%` thus centering the contents of the footer.

Here's a visual of how it looks after adding the above code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. Appreciate all the help on all my questions. You're a savior :)

Comment: Hey. I noticed when resizing the page the menu to the left gets cut off? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @crazythedon can't access the website, show's the coming soon page.

Comment: Sorry, it should be off now.

Comment: @crazythedon That's happening because your sidebar has a `fixed` position. You can try adding the following CSS to your stylesheet: `.widget_product_categories { left: 1%; }`.

Comment: Hi I tried that but it didnt seem to work. In which class do I have the sidebar fixed because I am unable to find it? Thank you.